# Git: Multiple projects under one directory

Tags: git

I have a question regarding how to best organize the following using Git.
I have multiple java and scala projects that are part of one effort. I would like to have the following structure:

```
/repos

    /java-project1

    /java-project2

   /scala-project1

  .....
```

Is it recommended that I do this:

```
mkdir repos
cd repos
```

Repos is a simple directory with 3 git repos inside it.

```
mkdir java-project1
cd java-project1
git --bare init .
```

on another machine

```
mkdir repos
cd repos
mkdir java-project1
git init
git add
git commit
git add remote origin [URL]
git push origin master
```

Do the same for other java and scala project?

or should I do `git init` in repos once and then just add the projects as three sub directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands seem legit, but for a quite specific conditions, where you have to manually initiate a bare repository on a server. Usually a Git server is used to provide access management and utility features.

This is done on a **remote** machine. A bare repository has no "usual" files in the directory, just internal Git files. It should also be accessible on the local network or by a URL (this is where a server is useful).

```
mkdir java-project1
cd java-project1
git --bare init
```

Note, that if you have some code or resources in `repos` (not in subfolders), it won't be under any source control. If you need a "nested" structures, look at submodules.

On your local machine.

```
mkdir repos
cd repos
git clone url1.git
git clone url2.git
git clone url3.git
```

Now you should have 3 repositories: empty and connected to their remotes (they will go by default name `origin` in each local repo)

If you're new to Git, I would recommend you to concentrate not on the commands, but on the understanding and workflow. This is like understanding architecture before developing some software. Spend a day getting to know how Git works. It will pay off later.

[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)